# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, db2

When I try to add into `TDEPOFAZLA` table, I get the following error:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [tr.gov.tcmb.pgmtems.model.DepoFazla]; SQL [insert into PGMTEMS.TDEPOFAZLA (ID, FAZLABULUNDURMAORANI, GRUP) values (default, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [tr.gov.tcmb.pgmtems.model.DepoFazla]

Here is my **JUnit** test function:

```
    @Test
public void testSaveDepoFazla() {
    DepoTur depoTur = new DepoTur("my tür", 5);
    depoTurService.saveDepoTur(depoTur);

    List<DepoTur> list = depoTurService.getDepoTurList();
    assertNotNull(list.get(0));

    BigDecimal fazlaBulundurmaOrani = new BigDecimal(6000);
    DepoFazla depoFazla = new DepoFazla(1, list.get(0), fazlaBulundurmaOrani);

    depoFazlaService.saveDepoFazla(depoFazla);
}
```

Here is my **DepoFazla.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "PGMTEMS", name = "TDEPOFAZLA")
public class DepoFazla implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2800365387332643658L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "GRUP", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INTEGER")
    private Integer grup;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = DepoTur.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotNull
    private DepoTur depoTur;

    @Column(name = "FAZLABULUNDURMAORANI", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(6, 2)")
    private BigDecimal fazlaBulundurmaOrani;

    public DepoFazla() {
        super();
    }

    public DepoFazla(Integer grup, DepoTur depoTur, BigDecimal fazlaBulundurmaOrani) {
        super();
        this.grup = grup;
        this.depoTur = depoTur;
        this.fazlaBulundurmaOrani = fazlaBulundurmaOrani;
    }
//GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

Here is **DepoTur.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "PGMTEMS", name = "TDEPOTUR")
public class DepoTur implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6203672609079710060L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Index(name = "XUTDEPOTURP", columnNames = { "id" })
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ACIKLAMA", nullable = false)
    private String aciklama;

    @Column(name = "BLOKESIRASI", nullable = false)
    private Integer blokeSirasi; //

    @Column(name = "DEPOCINSI")
    private String depoCinsi;

    public DepoTur() {
        super();
    }

    public DepoTur(String aciklama, Integer blokeSirasi, String depoCinsi) {
        super();
        this.aciklama = aciklama;
        this.depoCinsi = depoCinsi;
        this.blokeSirasi = blokeSirasi;
    }

public DepoTur(String aciklama, Integer blokeSirasi) {
    super();
    this.aciklama = aciklama;
    this.blokeSirasi = blokeSirasi;
}
//GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
```

When I debug the JUnit test, I get this error:

> Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=TBSPACEID=2, TABLEID=75, COLNO=2, DRIVER=3.50.152 SQLState: 23502 ErrorCode: -407

When I search the error, I find that I try to insert NULL but I can't figure out where I add null value.

This is how I create **TDEPOFAZLA** table:

```
    CREATE TABLE TDEPOFAZLA
(
   ID decimal(20,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   GRUP int NOT NULL,
   DEPOTUR decimal(20,0) NOT NULL,
   FAZLABULUNDURMAORANI decimal(6,2) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX XUTDEPOFAZLAP ON TDEPOFAZLA(ID);
```

This is how I create **TDEPOTUR** table:

```
CREATE TABLE TDEPOTUR
(
   ID decimal(20,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   ACIKLAMA varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   DEPOCINSI char(1),
   BLOKESIRASI int NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX XUTDEPOTURP ON TDEPOTUR(ID);
```

Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: do you have defined the getters/setters for all attributes?

Comment: `TDEPOFAZLA` has four not nullable column, while your insert statement provides fewer values. There's no default for `ID` in the table definition, and `DEPOTUR` is missing altogether. And why did you tag this with MySQL>

Comment: @cralfaro I have defined the getters/setters for all attributes and updated question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't reference the join column properly. This solved the problem:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPOTUR", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(20,0)")
@NotNull
private DepoTur depoTur;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you specified the same name for the join column Id twice in your **`DepoFazla`** model you have to change its name use for example :

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "PGMTEMS", name = "TDEPOFAZLA")
public class DepoFazla implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2800365387332643658L;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = DepoTur.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_depoTur", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotNull
    private DepoTur depoTur;

    ...

}
```

Comment: I have tried changing ID column names in database and in code. However, I still get the same error.

Comment: @supaplexy could you add the piece of Java code where prepare the object and persist it?

Answer (score 0):

Your property definition with the FK is wrong, as i saw you use updatable, insertable to false, you what really want is that the FK object is not modified because could be a master table common for some other entities.

Then what you can use is this

```
@ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPOTUR")
@NotNull
private DepoTur depoTur;
```

With DETACH, you will save the value only in the first table, column DEPOTUR and wont update the object in the DepoTur table

Also add the FK in your first table

```
CREATE TABLE TDEPOFAZLA
(
  ID decimal(20,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  GRUP int NOT NULL,
  DEPOTUR decimal(20,0) NOT NULL,
  FAZLABULUNDURMAORANI decimal(6,2) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX XUTDEPOFAZLAP ON TDEPOFAZLA(ID);
CONSTRAINT fk_column FOREIGN KEY (DEPOTUR) REFERENCES TDEPOTUR(ID);
```

Comment: @supalexy could you try what i added to my response? Change the mapping and create the FK, if still failing maybe i need you send the piece of code where you prepare the object and make the commit

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added my solution to the question.